# My Switch statement is not working as expected

Tags: java, switch-statement

I am currently trying to finish this program, however when I am testing my switch statement, it goes directly to my default case and says that I have entered invalid information.

**My Task**

I have to receive a month from the user and send it to my case statement in order to execute my code for the certain case.  As you may notice, that each case has a key in it, this key is for personal purposes.  Please disregard.

**My Problem**

case statement goes directly into my default statement, which issues an invalid information message to the user.

**My Progress**

This will be my complete program, everything seems to work properly except that my case statement recognizes every month as invalid input

```
// Import Libraries
    import javax.swing.*;
    import java.util.*;
    import java.io.*;


// This is my program.
public class DateCalc

{
public static void main (String[] args)
{
    String month;
    String day;
    String inputYear;
            Scanner  keyboard = new Scanner(System.in); 

                // receiving input for my age variable
                System.out.print( "Please Enter The Month Of The Date :");
                month = keyboard.nextLine();
                // receiving input for my weight variable
                System.out.print( "Please Enter The Day Of The Date : ");
                day = keyboard.nextLine();
                // receiving input for my height variable
                System.out.print( "Please Enter The Year OF The Date : ");
                inputYear = keyboard.nextLine();
                String stringYear = ""+ inputYear.charAt(inputYear.length()-2) + inputYear.charAt(inputYear.length()-1);
                int year = Integer.parseInt(stringYear);
                int intDay = Integer.parseInt(day);

        switch(month) 
        {  

          // I tried to test my program by using my first case " January ", However it goes right through every case directly for my default case.  

            case "January || january" :
            int janKey = 1;
            int janQuarter = year / 4;
            int janSum = year + janQuarter + intDay + janKey;

            System.out.print( " Date Entered Was : " + month + ","+ day + "" + inputYear);
            System.out.print( " Last Two Digits Of The Year Were : " + year);
            System.out.print( " One Quarter Of Last Two Digits : " + janQuarter);
            System.out.print( " The Given Day Of The Month Entered : " + day);
            System.out.print( " The Index Key This Moth is : " + janKey);
            System.out.print( " The Sum Of All The number Above is : " + janSum);
            System.out.print( " \n \n The Day Of The Week Was : ");
            int weekDay = dayLookUp(janSum);
            System.out.print( " \n \n The Day Of The Week Was : " + weekDay);
            break;


            case "February || february":  
            int febKey = 4;
            break;  


            case "March || march":  
            int marKey = 4;
            break;


            case "April || april":  
            int aprKey = 0; 
            break;

            case "May || may":  
            int maykey = 2; 
            break;

            case "June || june":  
            int junKey = 5; 
            break;

            case "July || july":  
            int julKey = 0; 
            break;

            case "August || august":  
            int augKey = 3; 
            break;

            case "September || september":  
            int septKey = 6; 
            break;

            case "October || october":  
            int octKey = 1; 
            break;

            case "November || november":  
            int novKey = 4; 
            break;

            case "December || december":  
            int decKey = 4; 
            break;

            //  IN MY DEFUALT CASE " inputValidation " WILL BE EXECUTED
            default:
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null," Invalid Entry Please Try Again " );

        }
}

public static int dayLookUp ( int janSum )
{
    int sum = janSum;
    int day = 14 % 7;
    return day;

}
}
```

Comment: `case "January": case "january":`

Comment: How do you expect your string with an `||` in it to magically work? You just have an odd string literal.

Comment: Yea you are right, I guess I tried to make every case preform like a conditional statement....That was really dumb of me <<<< lol @ myself

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The way you're doing it now, it's looking for the whole string as is, literally, not interpreting the `||` as any form of `or`.

You can either set the element in the switch to uppercase or lowercase use :

```
switch(month.toLowerCase()) {
    case "january" :
        ...
        break;
    case "february":
        ...
    ...
}
```

or you have to double case elements:

```
switch (month) {
    case "January":
    case "january":
       ...
       break;
    case "February":
    case "february":
        ...
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The mistake is at `"January || january"` this is one `String` use `case "January": case "january":`

Answer (score 1):

You cannot test for alternatives this way, `case "January || january":` doesn't work. You can give alternatives with multiple `case`s

```
switch (month) {
case "january":
case "January":
    int janKey = 1;
```

without an intervening `break`. This causes a fall through to the second case, when `january` is entered. The same is with the other months, of course.